# Can any Project Online data be accessed with the Graph Api?

Tags: rest, office365apis, project-online

The MS Graph API makes it easy to access SharePoint data, and it even has a [nice interactive explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) to play with.

Is there any way it can be used to get at any Project Online data, since Project Online is built on SharePoint?